# Child page in wordpress is broke layout

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

I install wordpress for my shop, and set up theme for it
But only layout of home page is normal, other pages is break layout
Ex: My home page is sample.com 
    Other page is sample.com/shoes 
    Home page is set to page: *homepage*
    Other page is set to page: *shoes*
[Home page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJISs.png)
[Other page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzMMe.png)

Does anyone know how to fix it?
  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you resolve your issue.
It seems a sidebar is use in product page, If you use full width template then problem will be resolved.

Comment: Your answer should be a comment, but you are not yet permit to comment, you can see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174/311885) why that is so. Please remove it and comment as soon as you have the reputation to do so.